# Adding short strings to a set in Ruby is slow

Tags: ruby, performance, set

I'm trying to extract all the unique characters from my utf-8 French dictionary file using this Ruby code. The dictionary is 3.7 MB. For some reason it takes my decent computer about half an hour to execute. Any ideas?

```
c = Set.new
f = open "dict"
s = f.read
f.close

for i in 0..s.length-1
    c << s[i]
end
```

Comment: Upon completion there were only 69 characters in the set. I don't see why it should take so long to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading in the entire file in one go before performing any computation on it prevents IO from being interleaved with computation. Furthermore, it increases memory pressure (potentially important if you're running close to the limit of your memory) and drastically reduces [cache coherency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence).

I wrote the following little script which executes in .3 seconds on my `/usr/share/dict/words` file -- less than a megabyte, but still large enough to be slightly interesting:

```
$ cat /tmp/set.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'set'

c = Set.new
f = open "/usr/share/dict/words"

f.each_char do |char|
    c << char
end

p c
$ time /tmp/set.rb 
#<Set: {"A", "\n", "'", "s", "B", "M", "C", "T", "H", "I", "D", "S", "O", "L", "P", "W", "Z", "a", "c", "h", "e", "n", "l", "i", "y", "r", "o", "b", "d", "t", "u", "j", "g", "m", "p", "v", "x", "f", "k", "z", "w", "q", "ó", "ü", "á", "ö", "ñ", "E", "F", "R", "U", "N", "G", "K", "é", "ä", "Q", "è", "V", "J", "X", "ç", "ô", "í", "Y", "â", "û", "ê", "å", "Å"}>

real    0m0.341s
user    0m0.340s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Your program was still executing one minute later, and I gave up.

The main difference is that mine uses the built-in iterators to read into a buffer a smaller amount of the file (probably 4k-16k) and hand me a specific character each iteration through. This will re-use the same small amounts of memory over and over again and allow the CPU's relatively small cache lines to store the entirety of the data.

**Edit**

With a small test case I was able to isolate the speed difference mostly to the `each_char` vs string sub-scripting. [Jörg points out that string subscripting is an O(N) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006711/adding-short-strings-to-a-set-in-ruby-is-slow/11006800#comment14392286_11006800) -- because UTF-8 strings cannot be simply indexed by multiplication as one might expect, finding the Nth character means starting from the beginning. Thus, your approach is O(N^2) and mine was just O(N), and *that* goes much much further to explaining the performance difference. I'm finally content that we figured out the core cause.

Comment: Holy cow! I can't believe how much of a difference that made! I've studied some data structure and algorithm efficiency stuff, but I had no idea that considering the cache could give such an improvement. I'm glad it wasn't because Sets are slow. I'll have to study this and think on it. Thanks!!!

Comment: I certainly wouldn't have expected your version to perform as much slower as it did -- I honestly would have guessed a factor of _10_ difference at the most. This was a complete surprise to me, and I can't help thinking that there must be more to it. (Perhaps it's largely due to the array subscripts vs iterator? More testing needed.) Anyway, this was a fun find. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it does seem to be mostly due to iterator vs indexing. I'm not sure why _that_ would matter, but there we go. :)

Comment: Finding the n'th character in a string is O(n). So, your solution is O(n), the OP's solution is O(n^2). Since n == 3.7 million, the OP's solution is roughly 4 million times slower, not 10 times.

Comment: BTW: this would more idiomatically written something like `File.read('/usr/share/dict/words').chars.each_with_object(Set[]) {|c, s| s << c }`

Comment: @Jörg, oh! Of course. We're living in the times of UTF-8, where character offsets cannot be computed with a simple multiplication. Your more idiomatic reading is nice to guarantee the file is closed when finished. This is the first I've seen `each_with_object`; it looks useful and is easier to understand than `foldl` from other languages. Thanks!

Comment: I also always forget about `each_with_object`, because it's so new. It's basically the "ugly" (i.e. mutable, impure) cousin of `inject`. Whenever you use `inject` just to mutate the accumulator and then return it, you can use `each_with_object` instead, which will ignore the block's return value and just thread through the accumulator for you. IOW: `inject {|a, e| do_something_with_a; a }` == `each_with_object {|e, a| do_something_with_a }`. In this particular case, both would work, actually, because `s << c` returns `s`, but `each_with_object` might be more efficient.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I think the String subscript operator _could_ be improved internally. (Maybe remember the last subscript used and find the next character based on that if the new subscript is 1 more or less than the old.) But this does make a lot of sense. Thanks for your great answers.